# How to replace values in multiple columns based on value from left-adjacent column

Tags: r, dplyr, across

I have data similar to this (though way bigger dataset):

```
  correct.trial1 RT.trial1 correct.trial2 RT.trial2 correct.trial3 RT.trial3
1              1       473              0       337              1       426
2              1       496              1       407              1       421
3              1       368              0       405              1       470
4              0       333              1       475              0       473
5              0       435              0       312              1       402
```

We can make this sample with this:

```
set.seed(12)
df <- data.frame(correct.trial1 = sample(0:1, 5, replace=T),
                 RT.trial1 = sample(300:500, 5, replace=T),
                 correct.trial2 = sample(0:1, 5, replace=T),
                 RT.trial2 = sample(300:500, 5, replace=T),
                 correct.trial3 = sample(0:1, 5, replace=T),
                 RT.trial3 = sample(300:500, 5, replace=T))
```

I would like to replace values `starts_with("RT.trial")` with `NA` when the adjacent (left) column `starts_with("correct.trial")` has value 0. Of course, I could do it one at a time, e.g.,:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(RT.trial1 = ifelse(correct.trial1==1, RT.trial1, NA),
         RT.trial2 = ifelse(correct.trial2==1, RT.trial2, NA),
         RT.trial3 = ifelse(correct.trial3==1, RT.trial3, NA))
```

So it would look like this:

```
  correct.trial1 RT.trial1 correct.trial2 RT.trial2 correct.trial3 RT.trial3
1              1       473              0        NA              1       426
2              1       496              1       407              1       421
3              1       368              0        NA              1       470
4              0        NA              1       475              0        NA
5              0        NA              0        NA              1       402
```

But that would be impracticable with thousands of columns.

#### Question

How can I do this for all columns simultaneously? (Note: I would prefer a `dplyr` solution, and using `across` would be preferable to using `mutate_at`.)

#### Attempt

Not sure, but based on this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54938540/replace-values-from-multiple-columns-based-on-value-from-adjacent-column), it would (maybe) look something like this:

```
df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("RT.trial")),
  ~ifelse(vars(starts_with("correct.trial"))==0, NA, .x))
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun, I just added a seed and updated the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could reshape to 'long' format and then do the transformation

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = -rn, names_to = c(".value", "grp"), 
          names_sep="\\.") %>%
    mutate(RT = case_when(as.logical(correct) ~ RT)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = c(correct, RT), 
          names_sep = ".") %>%
    select(names(df))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 6
#  correct.trial1 RT.trial1 correct.trial2 RT.trial2 correct.trial3 RT.trial3
#           <int>     <int>          <int>     <int>          <int>     <int>
#1              0        NA              0        NA              0        NA
#2              1       394              1       458              0        NA
#3              0        NA              1       337              0        NA
#4              1       479              0        NA              0        NA
#5              0        NA              0        NA              0        NA
```

---

In `base R`, this can be done in a more easier way

```
i1 <- grepl('correct', names(df))
df[!i1] <- (NA^!df[i1]) * df[!i1]
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(correct.trial1 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), RT.trial1 = c(417L, 
394L, 345L, 479L, 368L), correct.trial2 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L
), RT.trial2 = c(382L, 458L, 337L, 406L, 306L), correct.trial3 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), RT.trial3 = c(469L, 364L, 361L, 359L, 309L)),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Comment: Wow, amazing, thank you! I don't think I could have figured this out by my own. I didn't think about using another package and don't know `tidyr`. This solves the problem perfectly.

I am sorry I didn't add a seed from the beginning, I didn't think the exact values were relevant, just the general principle. You may remove the data creation part now that I have added a seed, if you wish.

Comment: @RemPsyc I added a `base R` approach, which should be more easier assuming that the 'correct' and 'RT' columns are corresponding and the data have only those columns

Comment: Thank you for adding the `base R` approach too. My data has more than these two columns (thus why I was asking for the `dplyr` approach), but this is perfectly fine for the current question.

Comment: @RemPsyc If that is the case you can have second `i2 <- grepl("^RT\\.trial\\d+$", names(df))` to subset the RT columns

Comment: Oh I see, the `dplyr` solution also doesn't work with multiple columns. It seems it's actually just breaking down when converting back to wide format at `pivot_wider()`. But I was able to fix it by simply adding the third column to `values_from = c(...)` :D Maybe you could just add a small Edit note saying: "if you have multiple columns, simply do this: ...".

Comment: @RemPsyc You can either `select` i.e. `df1 %>% select(matches('^(RT_trial|correct\\.trial"))` before going into pivot_longer or change the `cols=` in `pivot_longer` to that.  I would go with a subset of columns as it would make things efficient and faster

Comment: Yes, it worked adding the columns I DON'T want into `pivot_longer(cols =...)`, but I think there's a quote missing in `select(matches('^(RT_trial|correct\\.trial"))` because it's giving an error.

Comment: @RemPsyc sorry, it would be `'` instead of `"` the quote needs to be matched.  It is a typo.  Sorry

Comment: Oh ok the version that works fully is this: `df %>% select(matches('^(RT|correct\\.trial)'))` (parenthesis after the last `trial` and no `_trial` to `RT`). Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

This also works. It's the simplest way using across.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("RT.trial"), ~ if_else(get(str_c("correct.trial", str_sub(cur_column(), -1))) == 0, NA_integer_, .)))
```

This gives:

```
  correct.trial1 RT.trial1 correct.trial2 RT.trial2 correct.trial3 RT.trial3
1              1       473              0        NA              1       426
2              1       496              1       407              1       421
3              1       368              0        NA              1       470
4              0        NA              1       475              0        NA
5              0        NA              0        NA              1       402
```

Comment: You should load your packages in the beginning otherwise it won't work when people try to test it. I'm having an error: `could not find function "str_c"`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with `tidyverse` here is one more option :

```
library(dplyr)

purrr::map2_dfc(df %>% select(starts_with('RT')), 
                df %>% select(starts_with('correct')),
                ~if_else(.y == 0, NA_integer_, .x)) %>%
  bind_cols(df %>% select(starts_with('correct'))) %>%
  #To get correct order of columns
  select(order(as.numeric(sub('\\D+', '', names(.)))))

#  RT.trial1 correct.trial1 RT.trial2 correct.trial2 RT.trial3 correct.trial3
#      <int>          <int>     <int>          <int>     <int>          <int>
#1       473              1        NA              0       426              1
#2       496              1       407              1       421              1
#3       368              1        NA              0       470              1
#4        NA              0       475              1        NA              0
#5        NA              0        NA              0       402              1
```

Comment: Currently, this answer does not provide the expected output (the updated `trial` columns overwrites the `correct` columns).

Comment: Oops..you are right. Had to interchange columns. Updated answer should help @RemPsyc

Comment: That's better! :)